# Connect to Google Cloud MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I'm trying to connect to my MySQL database using a soft called [Beekeeper-studio](https://github.com/beekeeper-studio/beekeeper-studio). I created a SQL instance, inside I created a database (let's called it myDatabase) and a username and password (test and testPassword). And I tooke the public IP address on the overview page of this instace.

So I'm trying to make a connection to the db with the URL like that: `mysql://test:testPassword@XX.XX.XX.XXX:3006/myDatabase`

So when I'm trying to connect, i have a timeout error: `connect ETIMEDOUT XX.XX.XX.XXX:3006`

I'm trying to connect to the db before using it on my nodejs API. Any idea?

Comment: Please try to add these to the connection string`connectionLimit:15,
        queueLimit: 30,
        acquireTimeout: 1000000`

Comment: `mysql://user:pass@host/db?debug=true&charset=BIG5_CHINESE_CI&timezone=-0700` something like this

Comment: Are you connecting to the public IP of the instance?
Under "Connections" menu of the instance did you add your local IP to the list of authorized networks?

Comment: Connection Timeout means the Cloud SQL firewall is not allowing connections from your IP address.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to either:

1. Add your machine's IP to an [authorized network](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/authorize-networks), or
2. Run the [Cloud SQL Auth Proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/sql-proxy) on your machine.